# Универсальный обмен данными в формате XML

Tags: 1с

Добрый день, сообщество.

**Что мы имеем:**
 1. 1с предприятие 8.2 №1
 2. 1с предприятие 8.2 №2
 3. 1с конвертация данных

**Что делаем:**
 1. Создаем правила обмена в 1с конвертация данных
 2. Выгружаем данные из 1с предприятия №1 по правилам
 3. Загружаем данные в 1с предприятие №2

**В чем проблема:**
Создаются пустые контрагенты в главной группе, и не понятно почему.

[image]

**Что странно:**
 1. В событии "После загрузки" все новые контрагенты помещаются в соответствующую группу - Объект.Родитель = Справочники.Контрагенты.НайтиПоКоду...
 2. Изменение совпавших контрагентов запрещено, можно только создавать новые. Так что это не обнулившиеся старые контрагенты.
 3. У этих "пустых" контрагентов нет даже кода. Хотя в правилах экспортирования включена галочка "Генерировать код, если он не задан"

**Вопрос:**
 1. Почему они могут образовываться?
 2. Как можно избежать их создания?

---

Если нужна какая-то дополнительная информация - говорите.

Comment: Конфигурации одинаковые?

Comment: Конфигурации принципиально разные, но я постарался сделать передаваемые данные более-менее одинаковыми + гибкие настройки правил обмена.

Comment: В файле выгрузки посмотрите что выгружается. Т.е. надо определить на каком этапе косяк. На моменте выгрузки или загрузки. Если выгрузка, значит что-то не так с правилами, если в файле выгрузки все нормально, значит надо попробовать прологировать загрузку как-то...

Answer (score 1):

В 1С:КД есть поддержка отладки при загрузке/выгрузке правил через обработку "Универсальный обмен данными в формате XML", при отладке сразу увидишь где косяк.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]